# Bot Framework LUIS and QNA integration

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

We are building a chat bot with LUIS and QNA in c#. The approach is like when nointent is reached in LUIS it will invoke QNA maker and try to see if the asked question is available there or not . But if QNA mathes the asked question with multiple Question in knowledge base it will prompt with all such question and ask what the user actually meant. But the problem is when user selects any one of the question some times it matches any of my luis intents there by displaying wrong answer instead of going to QNA maker.

I was available to fix this by assigning such questions to nointents in luis. But i just wanted to know whether this is right approach or something else can be done for this.  Because it will be pain to actually sit and assign all such possible questions to nointents.

If some one else has approached this in different, please educate me with your approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is when user selects any one of the question some times it matches any of my luis intents there by displaying wrong answer instead of going to QNA maker.

It seems that some specific questions match your LUIS intents, but you want to get the answers to these questions from QnA maker. As your mentioned, you can try to test these specific questions in your LUIS app and [correct top scoring intent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/train-test#correct-top-scoring-intent) and assign it to `None` intent, and retrain and republish your LUIS app.

Besides, if you want your bot app call QnA maker first, then call LUIS. You can try to modify your project structure and logic to achieve it. For example, your bot app reach QnAMakerDialog first, if no answer meets a specific threshold score, then call your LUIS.